# Laravel route difference between {id} vs {tag}

Tags: laravel

I am new in Laravel pardon me if question is silly. I have seen a doc where they used

For get request

```
Route::get("tags/{id}","TagsController@show");
```

For put request

```
Route::put("tags/{tag}","TagsController@update");
```

What is the difference and benefit between this ? I understood 1st one, confusion on put route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no real difference as it’s just a parameter name, but you’d need some way to differential parameters if you had more than one in a route, i.e. a nested resource controller:

```php
Route::get('articles/{article}/comments/{comment}', 'ArticleCommentController@show');
```

Obviously you couldn’t use just `{id}` for both the article and comment parameters. For this reason, it’s best to use the “slug” version of a model for a parameter name, even if there’s just one in your route:

```php
Route::get('articles/{article}', 'ArticleController@show');
```

You can also use **[route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding)**. If you add a type-hint to your controller action for the parameter name, Laravel will attempt to look up an instance of the given class with the primary key in the URL.

Given the route in the second code example, if you had a controller that looked like this…

```php
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

…and you requested **/articles/123**, then Laravel would attempt to look for an `Article` instance with the primary key of 123.

Route model binding is great as it removes a lot of `find` / `findOrFail` method calls in your controller. In most instances, you can reduce your controller actions to be one-liners:

```php
class ArticleController extends Controller
{
    public function show(Article $article)
    {
        return view('article.show', compact('article'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally there's no practical difference **unless** you define a custom binding for a route parameter. Typically these bindings are defined in `RouteServiceProvider` as shown in the [example in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding)

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('tag', App\Tag::class);
}
```

When you bind `tag` this way then your controller action can use the variable via model resultion:

```
public function update(Tag $tag) { 
   // $tag is resolved based on the identifier passed in the url
}
```

Usually models are automatically bound so doing it manually doesn't really need to be done however you can customise resolution logic if you do it manually

Answer (score 0):

**Normal way**

```php
Route::get("tags/{id}","TagsController@show");

function($id) 
{
    $tag = Tag::find($id);
    dd($tag); // tag  
}
```

---

**With route model bindings**

```php
Route::put("tags/{tag}","TagsController@update");

function(Tag $tag) // Tag model binding 
{
   dd($tag); // tags  
}
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: Actually contusion is for put why they used {tag}, why not {id} ?

Comment: for route bing they use naming like this https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#implicit-binding

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [Route model bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)

Use id, Laravel will get the id from route, and it will be the tag's id, it is integer.

```
function show($id) {
    $tag = Tag::find($id);
}
```

Use tag, Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name.
In URL, your tag parameter is integer, however in your controller action `$tag` will be a model object:

```php
function action(Tag $tag) {
    $tag->name;
}
```

So you don't need to get the `$tag` by eloquent in your controller action.  You just need to specify it is From model `Tag $tag`
It will do it automatically.

Comment: it will automatically get the {tag} , do u mean tag object ?

Comment: @SatuSultana yes, you give the id in parameter `tag`, it will automatically change to tag object to `$tag` variable

Comment: Route model binding isn’t that simple. You’d need to add a type-hint to your controller action for it to work. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59610244/102205) for an explanation/example.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a convention. You can call it all you want. Usually, and {id} refers to the id in your table. A tag, or similarly, a slug, is a string value. A tag could be 'entertainment' for video categories, while 'my-trip-to-spain' is a slug for the description of a video.

You have to chose the words what you are comfortable with. The value will be used to find in your database what record is needed to show the correct request in the view. Likewise you can use `video/view/{id}/{slug}` or any combination thereof.

Just make sure your URLs don't get too long. Because search engines won't show your website nicely in search results if you do. Find the balance between the unambiguous (for your database) and logic (for your visitors).